# Tentando obter a propriedade 'id' de não-objeto com Array

Tags: php, laravel

Estou tentando pegar um ID do banco de dados, mas recebo o seguinte erro:

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object...

Meu código:

```
if($provider == null) {
                    $provider = array(
                        'provider' => $p->provider,
                        'items' => array($p),
                        'object' => User::find($p->provider),
                        'month' => array($order->id => $months)
                    );
                    $providers[] = $provider;
                }
```

O resultado irá me mostrar um filtro para um relatório:

```
<?php $__currentLoopData = $providers; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $provider): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
                <?php if($provider['object']->id != 3104): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo e($provider['object']->id); ?>" provider="<?php echo e(json_encode($provider),true); ?>"><?php echo e($provider['object']->name); ?></option>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo e($provider['object']->id); ?>" provider="<?php echo e(json_encode($provider),true); ?>" class="d-none"><?php echo e($provider['object']->name); ?></option>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; $__env->popLoop(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
```

O erro ocorre na linha `<?php if($provider['object']->id != 3104): ?>`
Uso o PHP 7.2.

Comment: E o que é `$order`?

Comment: É uma variável que recebe os pedidos.

Comment: Ok. E de que tipo ela é? Ela possui o campo `id`? Qual o retorno de `var_dump($order)`?

Comment: Em qual linha exatamente está dando esse erro? Por pode estar dando também em `<?php if($provider['object']->id != 3104): ?>` se `$provider['object']` por um acaso for `null` nunca se vai encontrar um `id` aí, e no seu `'object' => User::find($p->provider)` não há garantia nenhuma q `'object'` não vá poder ser null

Comment: Ela é do tipo nulo, setada quando necessária. Sim ela recebe o id do banco, que irá filtrar os providers.

Comment: O erro está dando em `<?php if($provider['object']->id != 3104): ?>`, mas antes estava funcionando normalmente.

Comment: @ErlonCharles E como eu poderia fazer com que o meu `object` não voltasse `null` da minha busca no banco? Eu atribuiria ele diretamente ao `id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma mais recomendad de garantir que você não terá um `$provider['object']` **null** é colocando uma verificação antes da montagem do `provider`

```
$user = User::find($p->provider);
if($provider == null && $user instanceOf User) {
    $provider = array(
        'provider' => $p->provider,
        'items' => array($p),
        'object' => $user,
        'month' => array($order->id => $months)
    );
    $providers[] = $provider;
}
```

O `instanceOf` vai verificar se a sua variável `$user` é de fato uma instância do seu model `User` assim garantindo que ela vai ter o atributo `id` que hoje ele reclama que não existe

Mas você também pode tratar isso na sua *blade*